# Ajax/jQuery cross-domain reuqest to PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services

I'm new to using Ajax and jQuery. I have been trying to send form data using jQuery to a PhP script.

This is my jQuery code:

```
alert('No errors: Form will be submitted:');

            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'http://myapplication.elasticbeanstalk.com/',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {nameInput: $('#name').val()},
                type: 'GET',

                success: function(response) {
                    alert("success!"+response);
                },

                error: function(){
                    alert("fail!");
                }
            });
```

PhP Code:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);


echo "----";
$return = $_GET['name'];

echo json_decode($return);
?>
```

The jQuery code runs in one server while the php runs in Amazon Cloud services. 
I keep getting an NS_BINDING_ABORTED error from the elasticbeanstalk server and I don't know why. I have tried everything to fix this including adding cross-domain headers to my $.ajax request and trying this with POST but nothing has helped so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is an interesting issue, and I would suggest you try three things: 
1). change `jsonp` to `json` - or omit that line, altogether. It isn't necessary. 
2). Remove the `echo "-----"` - that may cause other problems. 
3). It seems likely that the problem is that this request is being made twice. You could verify this with FireBug or by turning on XHR monitoring in your inspect element tool. If this is the case, in your submission function, you should throw in a debounce function, like: `if(typeof debounceCheck == 'undefined') { debounceCheck = true } else { return; }`

Comment: Thank you for your response rm-vanda. I removed the jsonp line and the echo "----". I'm not sure if it's due to some setting but XHR shows 0 requests.

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = "http://website.com/;
var XHR = window.XDomainRequest || window.XMLHttpRequest
var xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onload = function() {
$('#loadhere').html(xhr.responseText); 
}
xhr.send();

<div id="loadhere"></div>
```

And Necessarily add to all page

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```